# What are default methods that gets called when we scroll tableView iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic, uitextview

In my tableViewCell, I am trying to display dynamic content from CoreData string object in a textView with a background image. When the tableView is loading for the first Time, background image is stretching to right and text content in textView is trimming, but when I scroll the tableView, rect of background image is appearing as expected however, textView content is still trimming. can anyone please tell me what default methods will system call internally when we scroll a tableView? Because some method is setting my background Image rect correctly which i am failing to set in initial loading of tableView.

Comment: did you had a look at `UITableViewDelegate`? Your question is not clear, provide some code and describe better want you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Many more please check tableview data delegate and data source Methods.